# php can't get url content of the webpage

Tags: php, url, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the content of a Url and search for some values in it.
I've done this before and I had no problem but the method does not work on this Url:
https://steamdb.info/app/1060870/
I've tried

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://steamdb.info/app/1060870/");
```

But what I got was this

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in C:\wamp64\www\cont\tst.php on line 2
```

I also tried Snoopy library and it didn't work either.
Any suggestion ?
thanks in advance !

Comment: What part of `403 Forbidden` is a mystery to you?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like steamdb.info only accept the request if you specify a User-Agent in the headers of your request.

Edit : Look likes it works with those headers

```php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://steamdb.info/app/1060870/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cookie: __cfduid=d37d18f76a77fbb1d7e6c9422656437811602245996",
    "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.5",
    "Accept: */*"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

You need curl to run this (apt-get install php-curl on debian distro)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is more that steam doesn't want the content of this page to be accessible by some ways (like by a php program for instance)

If you try the same code with another URL (the one of this page for example), it's fine.

The 403 HTTP error code says : You are not allowded to see that page.

Comment: That's unfortunate ! Thanks for the info anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [puphpeteer](https://github.com/rialto-php/puphpeteer) to get the page.  You will have to set the headers.  I used this code to ensure I could get the html which you could modify and traverse with a Dom Parser.

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Nesk\Puphpeteer\Puppeteer;
use Nesk\Rialto\Data\JsFunction;

$puppeteer = new Puppeteer;

$browser = $puppeteer->launch();
$page = $browser->newPage();
$page->setUserAgent('Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.17');
$page->goto('https://steamdb.info/app/1060870/');
$data = $page->evaluate(JsFunction::createWithBody('return document.documentElement.outerHTML'));
print_r($data);

$browser->close();
```